# NSLog(@"%@",super) crashing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I used NSLog(@"%@",super) in a method(**any method**) and it is crashing.... Why? How to print the super contents?

Updated :

```
currentclassname : superClassName
{
}
```

and also if i use NSLog(@"%@", [super description]); It is printing `"<currentclassname: 0x3db7230>"` instead of superClassName... It is expected to print superClassName right.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When encountering the *keyword* `super` and a method call on it, the compiler generates a different call - [`objc_msgSendSuper*()`](http://17.254.2.129/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-objc_msgSendSuper) instead of the usual [`objc_msgSend*()`](http://17.254.2.129/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-objc_msgSend).

`objc_msgSendSuper*()` calls get an argument of type [`objc_super*`](http://17.254.2.129/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH3g-BBCFBBGA) instead of [`objc_object*`](http://17.254.2.129/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH3g-objc_object):

```
struct objc_super {
   id receiver;
   Class class;
};
```

So, `objc_super*` values aren't special instances, they have to be used with the special `objc_msgSendSuper*()` functions.

Thus, as Alex says, just call `-description` directly on `super` - its value is meaningless outside of the context its in unless you specifically use it with a runtime function like `objc_msgSendSuper()`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `-description`, e.g.:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [super description]);
```

If you have access to the superclass, you can override its `-description` method to return whatever information you want, or perhaps augment the class with a category.

Comment: Just interested - why variant in question does not work? Basically NSLog(@"%@",super) should call -description on super anyway, or not?

Answer (score 1):

`super` is a way to send a message to yourself and invoke the superclass's implementation rather than your own. It's not a separate object.

`NSLog` takes an object as the parameter to `%@`, and the object you mean to pass here is yourself.

Frankly, I'm surprised the code in question even compiles.

If you want to log your superclass's description of yourself rather than your own, then, as Alex Reynolds says, you must use a `[super description]` message for the parameter to `NSLog`. This sends the `description` message to yourself using your superclass's implementation, and passes the object that that message returns (the NSString object that is your superclass's description of yourself) as the parameter to `NSLog`.

But that's probably not necessary. If you have overridden `description`, that implementation can send `[super description]` and integrate that string* into the description string that it creates and returns. If you haven't overridden `description`, then a `description` message to `self` will hit the superclass's implementation anyway. Either way, pass `self`, not `super`, to your `NSLog` statements.

*There are several ways you could integrate the one string into the other; see [the NSString docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

> and also if i use NSLog(@"%@", [super description]); It is printing `<currentclassname: 0x3db7230>` instead of superClassName... It is expected to print superClassName right.

No. Using `[super aMethod]` instead of `[self aMethod]` just gives you the implementation of -aMethod that the superclass would use if it hadn't been overridden. `[self className]` and `[super className]` both resolve to NSObject's implementation which (I guess) interrogates the object's `isa` instance variable to get the name.

Answer (score 0):

Try `NSLog(@"%@",[super view]);`
or anthything like [super ANY_METHOD];
What exactaly are you trying to achieve from super?